# How to enable Icon for Bookmarking Websites on iOS 8?

Tags: html, web-applications, mobile-safari, ios8

It would seem like the standard apple-touch tags aren't working correctly for me in iOS8.

`<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="180x180" href="icon-180.png">`

Is there a new format to get this functionality to work? It looks like Apple hasn't yet updated their docs for iOS 8.

Answer (score 4):

I was having issues getting these to work, and the reason was that because I was using a development SSL certificate, it wasn't fetching the images properly.

When on a machine with a proper SSL certificate, or by using absolute paths with a non-secure protocol (http://), I was able to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the touch-icon link right after  fixed it for me.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="180x180" href="icon-180.png">
```

Comment: Adding it right after the meta tag fixed it for you? This didn't work for me.

Comment: It did. After upgrading to ios8 some of the touch icons did not load on the home screen. Those that loaded has the link right under the meta tag.